# CakePHP 3 - Export CSV controller function missing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cakephp-3.0, export-to-csv

I feel I followed the instructions for https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview.

1.I add public function export() to my controller.

```
public function export() {
        $this->response->download('export.csv');
        $data = $this->EstimatedRevenueFromCourseFees->find('all')->toArray();
        $_serialize='data';
        $_header = ['Semester', 'Total # of courses in the course bank', 'Total # of courses with approved fees', '# of courses offered', '% with fees', '# of courses with $100 & under', '% of courses with fees $100 & under', ' Revenue from $100 & under',
                    '# of courses with $100 & over', '% of courses with fees $100 & over', 'Revenure from $100 & over', '% of courses with fees $100 & over', 'Revenue from $100 & over', 'Total Revenue from course fees'];
        $this->set(compact('data','_serialize','_header'));
        $this->viewBuilder()-className('CsvView.Csv');
        return;
    }
```

1. installed plugin using composer and added to bootstrap.php:

   `Plugin::load('CsvView');`
2. added this to routes.php:

   `Router::extensions('csv');`

   3. added this to my view file:

   `<?= $this->Html->link('export', ['controller'=>'estimatedRevenueFromCourseFees', 'action'=>'export', '_ext'=>'csv'], ['class'=> 'btn btn-success']) ?>`

But when I hit the button I get the

```
Error: Create EstimatedRevenueFromCourseFeesController::export.csv()
```

Not sure what I'm missing. It does not seem to recognize the export function keeps added the .csv which I thought the router statement would adjust for.

Comment: I've found that if I remove the '_ext' => 'csv' from the view button then it works but it does not put the .csv on the downloaded file

Comment: Cake conventions would indicate that your controller name should be EstimatedRevenueFromCourseFees, not estimatedRevenueFromCourseFees (capital E at the beginning). No idea if that would cause this, but an easy thing to try.

Comment: Is that the complete error? I imagine there is more to the stack trace then that.